# iPad - biometric signature - getPressure touch

Tags: ios, signature, pen, pressure

I need to create an app for iPad, where the client can make a signature and i can get coordinates, acceleration and **pressure** of touch. For draw, coordinates and acceleration no problem. but i can't get pressure. I tried with `CPBPressureTouchGestureRecognizer` but I didn't solve. I could also use a pen and a sdk.

Someone can suggest something to me? Can i do all with finger or it's necessary a pen? What is cheaper pen and  easier sdk to use?

Answer (score 1):

iPad has no hardware capability of sensing the pressure. Unless it'd be some special stylus that sends the pressure info via BT to the iPad app - you're out of luck.

Also - you'd have to calculate acceleration yourself.

Comment: For acceleration, i implemented an algoritm. For pressure, do you know a stylus that i can use? i find pogo-connect, but i don't know if it is easiest and cheapest.